# Integral of the absolute value of an unknown function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

I was just wondering if there is a general way (method/formula) to antidifferentiate the absolute value of a function. As in, is there any way to find $\int|f(x)|dx $ given that I already know what $\int f(x)dx$ is? I am referring to the indefinite integral.

Comment: You would need to know a lot about the function. Consider the integral of $\sin(x)$. Over certain intervals, the integral is zero. But the integral of $|\sin(x)|$ is positive!

Comment: Do you speak of the integral over an interval or of the antiderivative?

Comment: It is always advisable to split the function in intervals to break modulus and then operate.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I meant the antiderivative. I reworded my question to make that more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int|f()| = \frac{|f(x)|}{()}\cdot ∫f(x)dx + c$$

Proof:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}\cdot\int f(x)dx\right)$$

$$= \frac{d}{dx}(\text{sgn}(f(x)))\cdot\int f() + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int f()\right)\cdot \frac{|f()|}{f()}$$ as $$\text{sgn}(f(x))=\frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}$$

$$= 0 + f(x)\cdot \frac{|f()|}{f()}$$ as $$\frac{d}{dx}(\text{sgn}(f(x)))=0$$ for all $f(x) \neq 0$

$$= |f(x)|$$

Therefore, $\frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}\cdot\int f(x)dx$ is a solution to $\int|f(x)|dx$ for all $f(x) \neq 0$ so the general solution must be $\frac{|f(x)|}{()}\cdot\int f(x)dx + c$ for all $f(x) \neq 0$